# Why is EF Core not working with AdventureWorks2019?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I've been trying out EF Core against AdventureWorks2019 restored to SQL Server running on Docker, but so far I've failed to get it to work.

When I try to query the database through the DbContext injected into the HotChocolate resolver I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The specified field 'BusinessEntityId' could not be found for property 'Person.Id'.

I tried to get the data manually (`"SELECT TOP 10 BusinessEntityId, Title, FirstName, LastName, MiddleName FROM Person.Person"`) using a raw `SqlClient` connection and it worked as expected with the same connection string I give EF Core:

```
"Server=localhost,3845;Database=AdventureWorks2019;User Id=SA;Password=mySuperStrongPassword;"
```

I truly have no idea why EF Core is being tripped up here. For reference, this is my `OnModelCreating` override:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
        .ToTable("Person", schema: "Person")
        .HasKey(p => p.Id);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
        .Property(p => p.Id)
        .HasField("BusinessEntityId");
}
```

What else do I need to do to get EF Core to properly query the database?

Comment: Try reverse engineering to see a working model

Comment: `.HasField("BusinessEntityId");` => `.HasColumnName("BusinessEntityId);`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov That was it! Wow.